# Javascript - Can't replace "<" word in string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, markup

I was doing some javascript while I noticed i can't replace a "<" word inside an html tag such as

```
<label id="label" > <eraseme> </label>
document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = document.getElementById('label').innerHTML.replace("<eraseme>", "Replaced");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhqvbd3y/2/)

Any solution ?

Comment: voila: http://jsfiddle.net/bhqvbd3y/3/

Comment: works for me in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zsv1yzyo/

Comment: Usually the browser escapes `<` in invalid HTML automatically. Have you tried `&lt;`?

Comment: the trick the browser pulled was convincing you the `<` never existed

Comment: Your mistake was to *assume* what `.innerHTML` contains, instead of *actually looking* at what it contains. Use `console.log( document.getElementById('label').innerHTML);`.

Comment: your browser is probably interpreting `<eraseme>` as html. Check these alerts out: http://jsfiddle.net/3s1oeycx/ The first you have an actual tag generated as `<eraseme></eraseme>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the following in the replace function.

```
document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = document.getElementById('label').innerHTML.replace("&lt;", "Replaced");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML characters "`&lt;`".

Comment: That's called entity and you will also need `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace < with an html number

http://jsbin.com/vehimu/1/edit

Comment: html entity, there is no such thing a html number :)

Comment: sorry i meant an html name http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm ccording to this website